# VBA Excel - Close WebBrowser1 after 2 seconds

Tags: excel, vba

I have UserForm1, and add a Intro gif. The gif should disapear after 2 seconds. I wrote a code for that:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()    
    'Include GIF
    ' HTML code for inserting the image with customized dimensions
    Dim htmlCode As String
    htmlCode = "<html><body style='margin:0; padding:0;'><img src='C:\Users\XX\Desktop\objects\vid.gif' style='width:100%; height:100%;'></body></html>"
    
    ' Navigate web browser control to insert the HTML with the image
    WebBrowser1.Navigate "about:blank"
    WebBrowser1.Document.write htmlCode
    WebBrowser1.Document.Close
    
    ' close after 2 secs
    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "LogoSt"
    
End Sub



Sub LogoSt()
    WebBrowser1.Close
End Sub
```

Getting a error message after 2 secs on initialize..
Hipe i translated right from german: the macro "Path"!'LogoSt' cannot be executed. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may have been disabled.

Why does the msg pop up? what should be the solution?

Comment: `LogoSt` needs to be in a standard module, not in your userform.  Or look at: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/can-ontime-execute-sub-in-userform-module.338309/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example which just clears some text from a textbox.

Userform:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Me.TextBox1.Text = "blah"  'set some text on form launch
    Set CallBackRef = Me       'set callback object to this instance of the userform
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3), "CallMeBack" 'runs a sub in a regular module
End Sub

Public Sub CallBack() 'called from `CallMeBack`
    Me.TextBox1.Text = ""  'text cleared after 5 sec...
End Sub
```

Regular code module:

```
Option Explicit

Public CallBackRef As Object  'code in userform sets this before using OnTime

Sub CallMeBack()
    CallBackRef.CallBack  'calls code in the userform instance
End Sub
```

Based on: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/can-ontime-execute-sub-in-userform-module.338309/